# Angular JS assign scope variable after HTTP post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to assign the scope variable after a HTTP post request.

controller:

```
storeApp.controller("formCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {          
  $scope.variableToBeAssigned= null;
}

$scope.formsubmit = function () {
         $http.post($scope.url, { "name": $scope.name}).
                    success(function (data, status){
                        $scope.variableToBeAssigned= "success";                            
                    })}
```

The formsubmit() function is called when the user submits the form. The "variableToBeAssigned" remains null even after the HTTP Post request.

Comment: Put your formsubmit() inside controller.

Answer (score -1):

You should place the function inside the controller,

```
storeApp.controller("formCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {          
  $scope.variableToBeAssigned= null;
  $scope.formsubmit = function () {
         $http.post($scope.url, { "name": $scope.name}).
                    success(function (data, status){
                        $scope.variableToBeAssigned= "success";
                        return($scope.test1);
                    })}

}
```

Comment: how do you say it does not fix?

Comment: So in my view, I output the variable "variableToBeAssigned"..It remains null itself and not "success".

Comment: Does the HTTP request result is 2XX? Maybe you get rejected by the server and then the `success` of the promise is not called.

Comment: The HTTP response seems to be fine. I was able to check the response and it is a valid response from the PHP script.

Comment: return inside `success` does nothing